Is there a way to edit docker-remote-api in ECS task definition?
I've been learning AWS lately, and I've been trying to run a simple task on Ecs cluster with EC2 instances. The task definition is just a simple one. It just pulling an image from my private ECR to run on ECS. However, I couldn't start the task and found ecs agent error logs about docker api version.

What I've found is that my task definitions always have these docker-remote-api versions that are lower than 1.24, and I couldn't find a way to edit it.
"requiresAttributes": [
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.28"
    },
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
        "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    },
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
    }
],

For more information, I tried the following OS on ECS clusters.

Amazon Linux 2023
Amazon Linux 2
Amazon Linux 2 (Kernel 5.10)

ECS agent version: 1.88
My question is do you have a way to create task definitions with specific docker-remote-api?
EDIT: Tested with an Nginx image from public ECR catalog also found the same error.
{
"family": "sample-nginx",
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "sample-nginx",
        "image": "public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:1.27-bookworm",
        "cpu": 0,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "name": "sample-nginx-80-tcp",
                "containerPort": 80,
                "hostPort": 80,
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "appProtocol": "http"
            }
        ],
        "essential": true,
        "environment": [],
        "environmentFiles": [],
        "mountPoints": [],
        "volumesFrom": [],
        "ulimits": [],
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
            "options": {
                "awslogs-group": "/ecs/sampl-nginx",
                "mode": "non-blocking",
                "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                "max-buffer-size": "25m",
                "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
            },
            "secretOptions": []
        },
        "systemControls": []
    }
],

"networkMode": "awsvpc",
"volumes": [],
"placementConstraints": [],
"requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
],
"cpu": "1024",
"memory": "3072",
"runtimePlatform": {
    "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
    "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
}

}

It looks like the issue is that the Docker version on your EC2 instances doesn’t support the newer API versions your task definition needs. This is pretty common if the EC2 instances are using an older Amazon Machine Image (AMI).
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html
or you can get the AMI with CLI also:
aws ssm get-parameter --name /aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id --region <your-region>

so Basically you should switch to a newer ECS-optimized AMI for your EC2 instances. These AMIs are pre-configured with the right Docker version and ECS agent to work smoothly with ECS tasks.
and if you are not willing to update the AMI you can update the ecs-agent manually:
sudo yum update -y ecs-init docker 
sudo systemctl restart ecs sudo
systemctl restart docker

but honestly, switching to a new AMI is usually easier and cleaner.
and for your last question, nope, you cannot explicitly specify or control the Docker Remote API version in a task definition in Amazon ECS. but you can do that otherwise, by using USER-DATA in your EC2, with specifying the preferred docker-api version within ssm parameter store or something if you want to be dynamic in that way.

Hi Fedi,
Thanks for your answer. I've tried both Amazon Linux 2023 and Amazon Linux 2(Kernel 5.10), which should be the latest version last I checked. The result is still the same. From what I've found, it seems like the error is due to the latest ecs optimize ami + ecs agent will only support docker api version >= 1.24, but my definition still has older version.

Can you provide me with your full task def, i will try to retry on my end, to see wether i'll get the same error or no.

Sure. I added the task definition. However, I use my private ecr in the image field, so I'm not sure how should I share it haha. I've just found this issue(https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/4129) on github. I'm starting to think that it's because my image, but I used docker with api version 1.47 to build it tho.

Yes, i believe it's an issue with the image as well, i tried the same configuration with a simple nginx image, and it went perfectly

Got it, thank you for testing things on your end. One more question. The task definition that you tried doesn't have docker-remote-api version < 1.24 right?

I created a new task definition that use an official nginx image from public ecr. Using Nginx image, I still got the same error, and my new task definition has older docker-remote-api version as well.
